# Explicit Euler method doesn't behave how I expect

Tags: python, numerical-methods, numerical, numerical-integration

I have implemented the following explicit euler method in python:

```
def explicit_euler(df, x0, h, N):
    """Solves an ODE IVP using the Explicit Euler method.

    Keyword arguments:
    df  - The derivative of the system you wish to solve.
    x0 - The initial value of the system you wish to solve.
    h  - The step size.
    N  - The number off steps.
    """
    x = np.zeros(N)
    x[0] = x0

    for i in range(0, N-1):
        x[i+1] = x[i] + h * df(x[i])

    return x
```

Following the article on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) I can plot the function and verify that I get the same plot: [image: Explicit euler].  I believe that here the method I have written is working correctly.

Next I tried to use it to solve the last system given on this [page](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/EulersMethod.aspx) and instead of the plot shown there I obtain this:

[image]

I am not sure why my plot doesn't match the one shown on the webpage.  The explicit euler method seems to work fine when I use it to solve systems where the slope doesn't change, but for an oscillating function it never seems to mimic it at all.  Not even showing the expected error gain as indicated on the linked webpage.  I am not sure what is wrong with the method I have implemented.

Here is the code used for plotting and the derivative:

```
def g(t):
    return -0.5 * np.exp(t * 0.5) * np.sin(5 * t) + 5 * np.exp(t * 0.5) 
    * np.cos(5 * t)

h = 0.001
x0 = 0
tn = 4
N = int(tn / h)

x = ee.explicit_euler(f, x0, h, N)
t = np.arange(0, tn, h)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, x, label="Explicit Euler")
plt.plot(t, (np.exp(0.5 * t) * np.sin(5 * t)), label="Analytical 
solution")
#plt.plot(t, np.exp(0.5 * t), label="Analytical solution")
plt.xlabel('Timesteps t')
plt.ylabel('x(t)=e^(0.5*t) * sin(5*t)')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Edit:

As requested here is the current equation I am applying the method to:

```
y'-y=-0.5*e^(t/2)*sin(5t)+5e^(t/2)*cos(5t)
```

Where y(0)=0.

I would like to make clear however that this behaviour doesn't occur just for **this** equation but all equations where the slope has a change in sign, or oscillating behaviour.

Edit 2:
Ok thanks.  Yes the code below does indeed work.  But I have one further question.  In the simple example I had for the exponential function, I had defined a method:

```
def f(x): 
    return x
```

for the system f'(x)=x.  This gave the output of my first graph which looks correct.  I then defined another function:

```
def k(x): 
    return cos(x)
```

for the system f'(x)=cos(x), this does not give expected output.  But when I change the function definition to

```
def k(t, x): 
    return cos(t)
```

I get the expected output.  If I change my function

```
def f(t, x): 
    return t
```

I get an incorrect output.  Am I always actually evaluating the function at a time step and is it just by chance for the system x'=x that at each time step the value is just the value of x?

I had understood that the Euler method used the value of the previously calculated value in order to get the next value.  But if I run code for my function k(x)=cos(x), I get output pictured below, which must be incorrect.  This now uses the updated code you provided.

[image]

```
def k(t, x):
    return np.cos(x)

h  = 0.1         # Step size
x0 = (0, 0)        # Initial point of iteration
tn = 10        # Time step to iterate to
N  = int(tn / h)   # Number of steps

x = ee.explicit_euler(k, x0, h, N)
t = np.arange(0, tn, h)
```

Comment: what is the equation?

Comment: Sorry on my phone now but the equation should be shown at the bottom of the second linked webpage.

Comment: The third example? If so, put the equation in your post and then the link can be broken and your post would not help anyone, this is a community, and the answers should serve others.

Comment: Yes the third and last example as already stated in the question.

Comment: I already found the problem, in a moment I publish my answer.

Comment: The main mistake is that you had omitted the variable y in your equation, and instead of solving the original equation, solved equation: `y' =-0.5*e^(t/2)*sin(5t)+5e^(t/2)*cos(5t)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have incorrectly raised the function g, you want to solve the equation:

[image]

From where we observe that:

```
y' = y -0.5*e^(t/2)*sin(5t)+5e^(t/2)*cos(5t)
```

Then we define the function `f(t, y) = y -0.5*e^(t/2)*sin(5t)+5e^(t/2)*cos(5t)` as:

```
def f(t, y):
    return y -0.5 * np.exp(t * 0.5) * np.sin(5 * t) + 5 * np.exp(t * 0.5) * np.cos(5 * t)
```

The initial point of iteration is `f0=(t(0), y(0))`:

```
f0 = (0, 0)
```

Then from Euler's equations:

```
def explicit_euler(df, x0, h, N):
    """Solves an ODE IVP using the Explicit Euler method.

    Keyword arguments:
    df  - The derivative of the system you wish to solve.
    x0 - The initial value of the system you wish to solve.
    h  - The step size.
    N  - The number off steps.
    """
    x = np.zeros(N)
    t, x[0] = x0

    for i in range(0, N-1):
        x[i+1] = x[i] + h * df(t ,x[i])
        t += h

    return x
```

Complete Code:

```
def explicit_euler(df, x0, h, N):
    """Solves an ODE IVP using the Explicit Euler method.

    Keyword arguments:
    df  - The derivative of the system you wish to solve.
    x0 - The initial value of the system you wish to solve.
    h  - The step size.
    N  - The number off steps.
    """
    x = np.zeros(N)
    t, x[0] = x0

    for i in range(0, N-1):
        x[i+1] = x[i] + h * df(t ,x[i])
        t += h

    return x

def df(t, y):
    return -0.5 * np.exp(t * 0.5) * np.sin(5 * t) + 5 * np.exp(t * 0.5) * np.cos(5 * t) + y

h = 0.001
f0 = (0, 0)
tn = 4
N = int(tn / h)

x = explicit_euler(df, f0, h, N)
t = np.arange(0, tn, h)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, x, label="Explicit Euler")
plt.plot(t, (np.exp(0.5 * t) * np.sin(5 * t)), label="Analytical solution")
#plt.plot(t, np.exp(0.5 * t), label="Analytical solution")
plt.xlabel('Timesteps t')
plt.ylabel('x(t)=e^(0.5*t) * sin(5*t)')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Dump `y'` and what is on the right side is what you should place in the df function.

We will modify the variables to maintain the same standard for the variables, and will `y` be the dependent variable, and `t` the independent variable.

Equation 2: In this case the equation  `f'(x)=cos(x)`  will be rewritten to:

```
y'=cos(t)
```

Then:

```
def df(t, y):
    return np.cos(t)
```

[image]

In conclusion, if we have an equation of the following form:

```
y' = f(t, y)
```

Then:

```
def df(t, y):
    return f(t, y)
```

Comment: I'm sure it's right, but I can't check it until the morning. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah ran out of space, I am updating the question.

Comment: I have updated the question with a further example to show how it doesn't behave as I expect for two examples.  This is probably because I have a misconception about how the method is supposed to work.  I agree your current answer fixes the problem I had for a specific equation, but does not clear up the part I don't understand to help me apply the technique to other problems as well.

Comment: Sorry equation is f'(x)=cos(x), x0 = 0.  Updated question to make it clearer.

Comment: I believe the solution of f'(x) = cos(x), with initial condition x0=0 should give the answer f(x) = sin(x). The plotted output I expect, should be following the sin curve but increasing in error with time.

Comment: @Aesir Already update my answer, some other doubt, I recommend to maintain a standard with the variables that you use so that you do not get confused.

Comment: Thank you, but what does the plot look like if you extended it say to 10 or 20 timesteps?  For me making the change you suggested, the error doesn't increase, it stays constant rather.  I expected the error to increase with time?

Also thanks for the effort you are putting in to answer my question, I appreciate it,

Comment: That is the advantage of the method of euler is of the order O(h^2)

Comment: The error does not accumulate, it depends on the time delta = h

Comment: Any more questions about your class questions?

Comment: These aren't for class.  This is for teaching myself.  But since you offered I don't really get what you mean by euler is of order O(h^2)?  On the wikipedia page linked in my post it says that "Euler is said to be a first order method."  Would that not mean O(h)?

Comment: When they say that it is a k-order order implies that no errors are obtained in that order, so the error is `O(h^(k + 1))`

Comment: I recommend you look for a more reliable source than wikipedia, for example papers, specialized books, etc.

Comment: Do you have a book you would recommend?